# Binding lost instance on manual trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to store the instance of the `DataTable` declared inside the constructor, this seems working until I trigger the `change` event of a filter manually. Infact, I have a select `#filter` which populate the `DataTable` instance, if I do:

```
$('#filter').trigger('change');
```

I can see the `instance` of the `DataTable`, but if I manual change the select option I get as instance value `null`.

This is my code:

```js
function ContactHelper() {
  this.init();
  this.contactsTable = null;
}

ContactHelper.prototype.init = function() {
  console.log('initialized');

  $('#filter').on('change', function() {
    let newData = {
      'first_name': 'foo'
    };
    
    console.log(this.contactsTable);;
    this.contactsTable.row.add(newData);
  }.bind(this));

  this.initContactsTable();
};

ContactHelper.prototype.initContactsTable = function() {
  this.contactsTable = $('#my-dataTable').DataTable({
    columns: [{
        data: 'first_name'
      }
    ],
    destroy: true,
  });

  $('#filter').trigger('change');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  let cHelper = new ContactHelper();
});
```

```html
<link  href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="my-dataTable" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<select id="filter">
  <option value="0">foo</option>
  <option value="1">foo2</option>
</select>
```

as you can see I binded `this` to the `change` event, is something wrong in my code?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twx0bdfq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `init()` method in the constructor you set the `contactsTable` to `null`. Try this:

```js
function ContactHelper() {
    this.init();
}
    
ContactHelper.prototype.init = function() {
    $('#filter').on('change', function() {
        let newData = {
            'first_name': 'foo'
        };
        
        this.contactsTable.row.add(newData);
    }.bind(this));
    
    this.initContactsTable();
};
    
ContactHelper.prototype.initContactsTable = function() {
    this.contactsTable = $('#my-dataTable').DataTable({
        columns: [{
            data: 'first_name'
          }
        ],
        destroy: true,
    });
    
    $('#filter').trigger('change');
};
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    let cHelper = new ContactHelper();
});
```

```html
<link  href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="my-dataTable" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<select id="filter">
  <option value="0">foo</option>
  <option value="1">foo2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: "*this inside of the callback doesn't refer to contacthelper*" - that's what .bind() does - changes the value of `this` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Converted to snippet - error goes away but no idea if it's "working"

Comment: Ah! Then it might be just `this.contactsTable = null;` which should be removed from the constructor.

Comment: @freedomn-m this works, but I don't understand why. So I don't need to declare the variable inside the constructor? Could someone explain me better this?

Comment: @sfarzoso In the code you provided you declare `this.contactsTable` in `initContactsTable()` which is called from `init()`. But after `init()` is called you set `this.contactsTable` to null again. So the next time something fires the `onChange` event on your `$('#filter')` object, `this.contactsTable` will be null again.

Comment: @JKL oh I see.. I really need to get some rest.. Thanks